# KeyError when unpacking nested record

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, nested

I have this code below which aims to unpack a nested record when found. Sometimes it works and sometimes it throws an error.

Would anyone have an idea how to resolve this?

**Data (Works):**

```
d = { 
    "_id" : 245, 
    "connId" : "3r34b32", 
    "roomList" : [
        {
            "reportId" : 29, 
            "siteId" : 1
        }]
}
```

**Data (Doesn't work):**

```
d = { 
    "_id" : 2, 
    "connId" : 128, 
    "Config" : {
        "Id" : 5203, 
        "TemplateId" : "587", 
        "alertRules" : [
            {
                "id" : 6, 
                "daysOfTheWeek" : [
                    "mon", 
                    "tue", 
                    "wed", 
                    "thu", 
                    "fri", 
                    "sat", 
                    "sun"
                ], 
            }
        ]
    }}
```

**Code (Dynamic):**

```
root = pd.json_normalize(d)
nested_cols = [i for i in root.columns if isinstance(root[i][0], list)]

l = [root.drop(nested_cols,1),]
for i in nested_cols:
    l.append(pd.json_normalize(d, record_path=i))

output = pd.concat(l, axis=1)
print(output)
```

**Traceback Error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/Max/Desktop/Azure/TestTimerTrigger/testing.py", line 30, in <module>
    l.append(pd.json_normalize(d, record_path=i))
  File "c:\Users\Max\Desktop\Azure\.venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\json\_normalize.py", line 336, in _json_normalize   
    _recursive_extract(data, record_path, {}, level=0)
  File "c:\Users\Max\Desktop\Azure\.venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\json\_normalize.py", line 309, in _recursive_extract
    recs = _pull_records(obj, path[0])
  File "c:\Users\Max\Desktop\Azure\.venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\json\_normalize.py", line 248, in _pull_records     
    result = _pull_field(js, spec)
  File "c:\Users\Max\Desktop\Azure\.venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\json\_normalize.py", line 239, in _pull_field
    result = result[spec]
KeyError: 'Config.alertRules'
```

**Expected Output:**

```
_id,connid,config.id,config.templateid,id,daysoftheweek
2,128,5203,587,6,[mon,tue,wed,thu,fri,sat,sun]
```

**Note:**
I know a `keyerror` is when the key in a dictionary cannot be located, however, I'm unsure how to go about resolving this.

Any help or guidance will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is looking for the key `Config.alertRules` in your dict like `d["Config.alertRules"]`. It is a nested dict so you should index it like `d["Config"]["alertRules"]`, how are you passing these keys?

This error probably does not occur for your first dictionary since there are no nested dicts there. (`d["roomList"]` is a list)